# How should I test AWS S3 with moto on Travis?

Tags: python, travis-ci, boto3, moto

Moto needs a credentials file, which does not exist on Travis. Travis fails with

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

See [example](https://travis-ci.org/MartinThoma/mpu/jobs/452736756) / [code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu/tree/fix-boto).

How can I fix this for travis? (Locally, it works)

### What I tried

I added the following environment variables ([source](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#environment-variables)) to my `.travis.yml`:

```
env:
  global:
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummy-access-key
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummy-access-key-secret
    - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

I still get the same error. The versions [in this build](https://travis-ci.org/MartinThoma/mpu/jobs/452778417) are:

- boto: 2.49.0
- boto3: 1.9.41
- botocore: 1.12.41
- moto: 1.3.7

Comment: See also: https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/1941